# Density of sampled exponential data, with sampling weights proportional to x itself

Tags: exponential-distribution, weighted-sampling

Suppose $p(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$. However, our probability of observing a *given* sample of $x$ (denoted $z$) is further proportional to $x$ itself, i.e., $p(z\mid x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$. What is $p(z)$?

In R, I can characterize the distribution empirically:

```
n = 1e5
r = 0.1
x = rexp(n,r)
z = sample(x,n,replace=TRUE,prob=x)
hist(z,100)
```

which seems to be gamma-distributed, with $\alpha = 2$ (shape) and $\beta = \lambda$ (rate). Is this right? How to derive $p(z)$ mathematically?

For context, $x$ is distributions of durations spent in an open population, and $z$ are the observed durations in this sample. TIA.

---

**EDIT:** The accepted answer (and comments below the question) highlight parts of my question which are posed incorrectly / badly described. I'll leave them unchanged here, but n.b. the answer states the question more correctly and precisely.

Comment: You ask three different questions: one in the title, another in the text, ($e^{-\lambda x}$ is not proportional to $x$), and a third in the code (it seems closer to the title question, but because it's guaranteed to produce many tied values, has a tenuous relationship to either of the first two versions).  Shall we take the title question to be the intended one?

Comment: The code is my best understanding of the task. Does the context help clarify my goal? Not sure what you mean by "$e^{-\lambda x}$ is not proportional to $x$" --- of course it's not in general, but in this context, the chance of observing duration $x$ is indeed proportional to $x$ (at steady state, etc.). The "ties" are therefore intentional. Thanks,

Comment: It is very difficult to see how sampling one sample with replacement could possibly model "durations" (a concept I think I interpret as intended) in an "open population" (whatever that might mean). I also don't follow your "in general" argument: there is *no* specific situation in which $e^{-\lambda x}$ is proportional to $x$ unless $x$ can take on at most two distinct values.

Comment: In a population where people can enter/exit (e.g. sex work, being vegan), the durations of time spent in the population (x) are assumed to be exponentially distributed. However, with a cross-sectional study of the current population, reported durations will be biased high versus the durations of people *ever* in the population, because short-duration people leave quickly (sorry, this ever-vs-current distinction was not clear above).

Comment: Re proportionality, I should have clarified last comment: it is not $x$ itself which is proportional to $e^{-\lambda x}$, but the *probability of observing* $x$ is proportional to $x$, because a person in the population for $x = 10$ years, will have 10x the probability of being observed in a random cross-sectional study, than a person who remains in the population for $x = 1$ year.

Comment: Thank you -- I was hoping it would be some scenario like that.  The title captures it, but not your initial description.  I can see how the code works, now, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, suppose you are sampling a random variable $X$ from a distribution $F_X$ and the sampling intensity is proportional to some nonnegative function $h$ defined on the support of $X.$

Let $U$ be the random variable indicating whether $X$ is sampled, so that $\Pr(U=1\mid X=x)$ is proportional to $h(x).$  This specification of the conditional distribution (of $U$) along with the marginal distribution (of $X$) determines the joint distribution of $(X,U),$ so we should be able to figure out anything we want.  In particular, what is the distribution of $X$ conditional on $U=1,$ which is the *observed* value of $X$? By an elementary characterization of conditional probability,

$$\Pr(X \le z\mid U = 1) \ \propto\ \Pr(X \le z, U = 1)$$

(the constant of proportionality being just $1/\Pr(U=1),$ whose denominator we must assume is nonzero).  Furthermore

$$\Pr(X \le z, U = 1) = \int^z \Pr(U=1\mid X=x)\,\mathrm d F_X(x)\ \propto\ \int^z h(x)\,\mathrm d F_X(x).$$

This shows the distribution function for the *observed* values of $X$ must be

$$F_Z(z) = \frac{\int^z h(x)\,\mathrm d F_X(x)}{\int h(x)\,\mathrm d F_X(x)}.$$

> That is, *the probability measure for the observed version of $X$ is proportional to the probability measure for $X$ multiplied by the sampling intensity.*

In your case, the support of $X$ is the positive numbers and, for positive numbers $x,$  $\mathrm dF_X(x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}$ and $h(x)$ is proportional to $x$ (*not* $e^{-\lambda x}$!).  Consequently

$$F_Z(z) \propto \int_0^z x\, e^{-\lambda x}\,\mathrm d x$$

and this is recognizable as a Gamma$(2,\lambda)$ distribution.  Its expectation is twice that of $X.$

---

Incidentally, if sampling *were* proportional to $e^{-\lambda x},$ the answer would be

$$F_Z(z) \propto \int_0^z e^{-\lambda x}\,e^{-\lambda x}\,\mathrm d x\ \propto\ 1 - e^{-2\lambda z}.$$

This is an exponential distribution with half the expectation of $X.$

Comment: Excellent -- thanks for trudging through my poorly understood / posed question!